# React-Native Form Validation error ("this.validate is not a function")

Tags: reactjs, validation, react-native

I get this this error when I click "this._onPressButton"  using the below code. Unable to figure out why this occurs or to find a solution. Thanks in advance.

[image: Error]

```
import React, {Component}  from 'react';

import {View, Text, TextInput, TouchableHighlight} from 'react-native';

import ValidationComponent from 'react-native-form-validator';

export default class FormTest extends ValidationComponent {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {name : "My name", email: "tibtib@gmail.com", number:"56", date: "2017-03-01"};
  }

  _onPressButton() {
    // Call ValidationComponent validate method
    this.validate({
      name: {minlength:3, maxlength:7, required: true},
      email: {email: true},
      number: {numbers: true},
      date: {date: 'YYYY-MM-DD'}
    });
  }

  render() {
      return (
        <View>
          <TextInput ref="name" onChangeText={(name) => this.setState({name})} value={this.state.name} />
          <TextInput ref="email" onChangeText={(email) => this.setState({email})} value={this.state.email} />
          <TextInput ref="number" onChangeText={(number) => this.setState({number})} value={this.state.number} />
          <TextInput ref="date" onChangeText={(date) => this.setState({date})} value={this.state.date} />

          <TouchableHighlight onPress={this._onPressButton}>
            <Text>Submit</Text>
          </TouchableHighlight>

          <Text>
            {this.getErrorMessages()}
          </Text>
        </View>
      );
  }

}
```

Comment: There is no validate function within that code you are showing, which explains the error.

Comment: Any idea on what should be done in Call ValidationComponent validate method @JojoNarte

Comment: I think you have your classes and imports mixed up. Based on what you provided this error makes sense. What is this.validate? It looks like you should have imported validate from react-native-form-validator...

Comment: Thank you, any example on how this form validation should be done. Unable to find solutions.
[link] (https://github.com/perscrew/react-native-form-validator/issues/1)
@GavinThomas

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that they forgot to "bind" the function in their example

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {name : "My name", email: "tibtib@gmail.com", number:"56", date: "2017-03-01"};
this._onPressButton = this._onPressButton.bind(this)

  }
```

UPDATE:
I think you would need to use this propthis.isFormValid()

if it is valid, you could submit your form...etc

Comment: Thank you. Now the error went off but nothing happens on clicking onSubmit

Comment: Are you expecting it to throw errors because you're giving it bad data? If you are only using this package to validate form data I would suggest just doing it from scratch... Here is a link to my singupComponent that I validate data using REGEX... https://github.com/GavinThomas1192/motoMechanicMeeKanic/blob/master/App/Containers/SignUpScreen.js 
In the meantime I will check with the docs of the package you're using

Comment: Yes Gavin, thank you. I will start trying the one you gave.

Comment: Here is the link to the one which I'm tyring [link] (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-form-validator)

Answer (score 0):

the problem is in the onPress assign. 
Do it this way:

```
<TouchableHighlight onPress={() => {this._onPressButton}}}>
    <Text>Submit</Text>
</TouchableHighlight>
```

If you do `onPress={this._onPressButton}` this._onPressButton will be called automatically without been pressed. You must to put onPress functions inside arrow function like `onPress = {()=> {//HERE YOUR FUNCTION}}`